# Failed to load package list when updating 12.10 (fresh install)

Tags: updates, software-center, package-management

Thanks in advance for your time. Please pardon if this question was answered before (I tried to look for relevant questions - but found none). I am okay to work within the terminal but with limited knowledge - basically I am a noob. So I apologize for my lack of knowledge and mistakes I have done.

I installed 12.10 last night and unable to update it now. I tried to install medibuntu ppa to get updated codecs. However since then, I am getting the error `Failed to load the package list` and in details it says `E:Type '<html>' is not know on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/source.list.d/medibuntu.list`

I tried to delete the file all together but no option to do that. From another post on AskUbuntu, I tried to run:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

To that, I get the same response `E: Type '<html>' is not known on` I have already unchecked all the sources in update center to no avail.

Is there any hope to come out of this loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mediubuntu doesn't exist anymore, so the best thing you could do is remove it from your ppa's list:

```
sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/source.list.d/medibuntu.list*
```

And try again the update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this didn't work either. Giving me same exact error message.